How to add an image to a dataset in Langsmith
I am trying to add an image to a dataset to be able to test my application in Langsmith. I created a key value pair dataset. I can easily add variables, but I have no clue how I can add images. It seems to expect  JSON so I converted my image to base64, but it still doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
I tried this:
{
  "image": {
    "type": "image_url",
    "image_url": {
      "url": "data:image/JPG;base64,iVBORw0K...AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
      "detail": "high"
    }
  }
}

Initially I was thinking of doing this through the UI, but if you have a solution that uses the API that's fine as well!
